# How to set the value of a MeshPolygonStringProperty to a string?

Tags: python, mesh, import

I am trying to set a string attribute per polygon on a mesh. To create the property, I use:

```
a = m.polygon_layers_string.new(name='object')
x = a.data[0]
```

but when I try to set the data:

```
x.value = 'blah'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: MeshPolygonStringProperty.value expected a bytes type, not str
```

When I inspect the types:

```
type(x)
<class 'bpy.types.MeshPolygonStringProperty'>
```

and

```
type(x.value)
<class 'bytes'>
```

But [the documentation here mentions](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.90/bpy.types.MeshPolygonStringProperty.html#bpy.types.MeshPolygonStringProperty) the type of `x.value` should be a string, or am I misreading?

What is the correct way to store a string per polygon?

Answer (score 1):

**Use the `bmesh` API**

Suggest using bmesh for polygon string layers.

```
import bpy
import bmesh   

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)
str_layer = bm.faces.layers.string.new("Foo")

for f in bm.faces:
    f[str_layer] = bytes(f'Face {f.index}', 'utf-8')  # b`foo`
    
bm.to_mesh(me)
bm.clear()

for s in me.polygon_layers_string:
    print(f" Layer {s.name}")
    for p in s.data:
        print(p.value.decode())
```